# Django- understanding how information is displayed on webpage

Tags: python, django, view

I have recently taken over the development of a Django/ Python project, and am looking into fixing a particular bug within the system as it currently stands.

There is a database of projects with quite a large amount of information about each project stored. On one of the webpages, there is a button, which when clicked will add a new form to the page- the form allows the user to enter some details about a new object for the given project. If there are existing objects for that project within the database, a 'table' will be displayed with a form on each row for each of the existing objects, and the user can manually update the fields in the form to update the information about each of the objects in the database. They can also add a new 'row' to the 'table' to create a new object to add to that project.

This page is displayed by the view:

```
def current_ccis(request, budget_id):
    """
    View the CCIs for the current budget
    """
    budget = Budget.objects.select_related('project').get(id=budget_id)
    project = budget.project
    ccis = CciItem.objects.select_related('budget', 'budget__project', 'project_room', 'project_room__room').filter(budget_id=budget_id).order_by('project_room__order', 'created')

    formset = CciItemFormset(queryset=ccis.exclude(name=None), form_kwargs={'project':project})

    context = {
            'ccis': ccis,
            'project': project,
            'budget': budget,
            'formset': formset,
            'widths': ['60px', '120px', '220px', '120px', '60px', '60px', '60px', '280px', '280px'],

            }
    return render(request, 'costing/ccis_current.html', context)
```

The first cell in each `form` of the `formset` for each object displays the 'type' of object that it is, and every other cell displays/ stores other information relevant to the object itself.

On another one of the webpages, there is then a report displayed about a given project which includes information based on what the user input into the forms on the page displayed by the view `current_ccis(request, budget_id)`

This page is displayed by the view:

```
def report_ccis(request, project_id):
    """ CCI items styled for pdf """
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    budget = get_current_budget(project_id)

    cci_total_exc = budget.cci_total_exc_vat_final
    cci_grouped_items = budget.cci_items.all().order_by('project_room', 'name')

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'cci_total_exc': cci_total_exc,
        'cci_grouped_items': cci_grouped_items,
        'webview': 1,
    }

    try: context['current_budget'] = project.budget_versions.get(current_marker=1) #For option name/date on top of pdfs
    except ObjectDoesNotExist: pass

    if request.GET.get('stage') == 'pd':
        """ Render post deposit homepage """
        context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report2_ccis.html', context)
        context['active_tab'] = '4'
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_post_deposit.html', context)
    else:
        """ Render pre deposit homepage """
        context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report_ccis.html', context)
        context['active_tab'] = '5'
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_pre_deposit.html', context)
```

and the report currently displays the information in the format:

> Title
>
> Project ID
>
> Object
>
> ```
>   detail
>
>   detail
> ```
>
> Object
>
> ```
>   detail
> ```

i.e. a list of Objects belonging to the project, and underneath 'Object title' a list of details belonging to that object.

The issue that I'm having here, is that for some projects, the 'Object' names are all displayed with their 'details' listed beneath each 'Object', but for others, the details are not listed under their respective 'Objects', but rather all listed under one 'Object', which is titled "None"...

What I don't understand, is why there is this inconsistency- why is that for some projects, the 'Object' names are shown on the report, with all of the 'details' listed under their respective 'Objects', but for other projects, all of the 'details' are listed under the Object 'None'...?

Anyone have any suggestions why this is?

**Edit**

The reports are displayed in the HTML files with:

(post deposit):

```
{% block tabs %}


    {% with 'Payment schedule,Agreed variations,Variations not yet finalised,Client choice items,Overview'|listify as tabs %}
        {% for tab_name in tabs %}
            {% with forloop.counter as tab %}
                {% if not tab == active_tab|add:0 %}<a class="tab" href="{% url 'costing:report2_tabbed' project.id %}?tab={{tab}}">{% else %}<a class="active tab">{% endif %}{{tab_name}}</a>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock tabs %}
```

(pre deposit):

```
{% block tabs %}
    {% with 'Overview, Construction budget, Schedule of works, Client choice items'|listify as tabs %}
        {% for tab_name in tabs %}
            {% with forloop.counter as tab %}
                {% if not tab == active_tab|add:0 %}<a class="tab" href="{% url 'costing:report_tabbed' project.id %}?tab={{tab}}">{% else %}<a class="active tab">{% endif %}{{tab_name}}</a>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock tabs %}
```

**Edit**

The files where this HTML comes from both extend from the same HTML file (reports_tabbed.html), which has the following HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles utilities %}

{% block head_extras %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "moon/scss/pdf-reports.css" %}">
{% endblock head_extras %}

{% block page_options %}
    {% if request.user.first_name in 'Becky,Duncan'|listify and project.deposit_received %}
        <a href="{% url 'costing:pdf2_master' project.id %}?quick-pdf=1" target="_blank">Make quick PDF</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock page_options %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="tabbed m-r-lg text-sm">
        <div class="navbar tabbed text-sm">
            {% block tabs %}
            {% endblock tabs %}
        </div>

        <div class="tabbed-section border {% block tabbed_class %}page{% endblock tabbed_class %}">
            {{html}}
        </div>
    
    </div>

{% endblock content %}

{% block content_scripts %}

{% endblock content_scripts %}
```

Comment: You are aware that the references to the "html" files at the last lines of watch view are references to template files that actually use the information stored in the objects yielded above to be displayed, aren't you?

Comment: Yes- I've just added the HTML that's being used to display these reports

Comment: i can see that provided html is used to render tabs, but not structure in which you have problem. Are you sure that there is no other html file?

Comment: Both of those HTML files `extend` from the same HTML file- maybe there's something in that? I'll post the code for it now...

Comment: I've added the code for the HTML file that these other two HTML files extend from...